# Save file in selected location

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, save-dialog

On site (ASP.NET) i have table with items. Every item has link to specific pdf. This pdf i generate from binary data that are saved in database. So realy, i don't have path to pdf file. 
When i click on link, i want to download file. And this functionallity work fine. 
But i download file to default location that use browser (By default it's `C:\Users\Admin\Documents`)

What should i do to make browser show save dialog where user can chose destination path for pdf?

Code to generate pdf file :

```
private void ProcessFile(byte[] file, string fileName)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));

        Response.BinaryWrite(file);

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

---

About my code : i'm going to rewrite a bit it according to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx)

Comment: use savefiledialog -> http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog

Comment: @SimoneRiboldi, sorry, but i don't use WinForms. My problem is with ASP.NET

Comment: Using a web application, I thinks there is no way of doing that. The browser is the only one to decide.

Comment: @fantastik78, so it's possible to do with setting of browser, isn't it?

Comment: @demo if you use Google Chrome you can ask him to promt a dialog box each time you download a file: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574?hl=en

Comment: @fantastik78, thanks, i have already found it.